# Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown> (Kotlin Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

Before beginning, I have to say that I do not have huge image in my project

The problem is my **app runs in android 13** with no problem, But **it does not run in android 6** (app stops immediately)

And I have this error : `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sepehrfarm/com.example.sepehrfarm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>`

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:id="@+id/sepehrText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sepehrName"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview0"

        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="21dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sepehr_logo"
                android:padding="2dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sepehrText">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logintxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="@string/login_txt"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/phone_icon"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/black"
                android:hint="@string/phoneNum_txt"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/lock_icon"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/black"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:hint="@string/password_txt" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:text="@string/forget_password_txt"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:text="@string/login_txt"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>



        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/otp_login_layout"

        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_with_phone_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
            android:text="@string/otp_login_txt"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActiviy.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

build.gradle (:app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.sepehrfarm'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sepehrfarm"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SepehrFarm"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do not understand the problem, I will be grateful if you help me find the solution.

**I have read the current solutions** but it did not help

Comment: It seems some resources is not available in your APK on Android 6. check your res folder to see if you overridden some xml resources for higher api levels. also check if all resources you used are compatible with lower API levels.

Answer (score 0):

That line refers to `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"`.

Try using `android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceListItemSmall"` or `android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"` and see if it helps. Usually `android:` prefixes are targeted towards higher API levels and Android 6 might require support library access.